# Responding to Skype call, while in a video conference, the other person cannot hear me

Tags: android, skype, microphone, android-audiomanager, video-conferencing

So I am working on a video conferencing app, And I have to make a onHold functionality. But I noticed that if I get a skype call while in a conference, there are some issues with the microphone. The other user cannot hear me.
So I started some tests.
The same thing happens if I am on a whatsapp call, and I answer Skype, the other user cannot hear me.
If I am in my app and answer a Whatsapp call, the other person cannot hear me, and the app hangs.
If I am in Skype and I get a Whatsapp call, the same thing happens, it hangs, and no mic.
Is this a known Android Issue?
Is there any way to make my app "liberate" the microphone? so that Skype/Whatsapp can get access?

I can't really add any code here, not for Skype and WhatsApp, and for my app, when I get on hold, it calls onPause which does this:

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(TAG, "onPause Begin");
    LmiVideoCapturer.onActivityPause();
    mIsOnPause = true;
    pauseCall();
    if (cameraStarted) {
        cameraPaused = true;
        cameraStarted = false;
    } else {
        cameraPaused = false;
    }
    if(app != null) {
        app.DisableAllVideoStreams();
    }
    if(audioManager != null)
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(prevValue);
    Log.i(TAG, "onPause End");
}
```

Where DisableAllVideoStreams is a native c method. Also onActivityPause.

I even tried setting the audio focus, onPause and onResume like:
Pause:

```
audioManager.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE, AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS);
```

Resume:

```
  audioManager.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE, AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

But that does not help.